# One modem, 3 routers (3 access points) no connection between the routers

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, modem

So, before explaining this is the situation drawn out:

```
  ------- Router_1 
  |
Modem --- Router_2
  |
  ------- Router_3
```

Three routers on 3 seperate floors of the building all connected to the modem (lan-cables through the walls attached to the modem). So that means 3 access points on each floor and there is no way to connect the routers to each other. Every time you go to a different floor of the building you manually change your access point on your device, i.e. phone, laptop, etc...

How do I, or can I even do it, create a "single access point" like in a Wifi-Mesh where it switches automatically to the stronges signal, without needing to manually switch between routers.

Edit 0:

So a potential solution would be something like this:

```
                    ------- Router_1 
                    |
Modem -- Router_0 --------- Router_2
                    |
                    ------- Router_3
```

And then put Router_1, Router_2, Router_3 to bridge mode?

Edit 1:

So how I'm going to try to do it:

```
                               ---PoE/lan---------- Router_1 (bridge mode)
                               |
Modem -- Router_0 -- 5-port switch (with PoE) ---PoE/lan------ Router_2 (bridge mode)
                               |
                               ---PoE/lan---------- Router_3 (bridge mode)
```

Any pitfalls?

Or should I just get 3 TP-Link TL-WA801N N300 WiFi AP/Repeater instead of the routers acting as an AP?

Comment: so the problem is your APs are actually routers. Can you put your routers in "bridge" mode? if so, I'd start by putting a router inline between router 1 and the modem (router 0 if you will). then take the cables connecting the routers 1-3 to the new router. then put your routers 1-3 into bridge mode and disable DHCP. Then you would have one single network. reconfigure the routers to all use the same SSID, but different channels and you should be ready to go! The device should pick the best channel for it dynamically

Comment: @FrankThomas See edit pls.

Comment: Yes i believe that should work. be sure to disable DHCP on the routers 1-3. for the APs those TPLink APs are old and not particularly fast, and while I would suggest replacing the routers with APs if you want to spend the money, if you can put the routers in bridge mode and manually select channels, you don;t need to.  The switch in your diagram looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use a AP with built-in mesh. It's easy to create a mesh with Unifi APs for example. Unffortunatly i haven't found a cheap AP to use this function.

Comment: I basically have the 3 routers and think I can use them as APs. The lan-cables (all 3 of 'em) are connected with the modem and the respective routers. I was thinking about getting a WiFi-Mesh, but perhaps I can could use my routers in such a way that it could become like a WiFi-Mesh of sorts. Would the situation in the first edit work or could some unforeseen problems occur?